# Версии software поддерживаемые конкретной ОС версией

Tags: linux, centos, пакет

Как при обновлении пакетов на ОС узнать список всех существующих пакетов данного софта для данной операционной системы. Что-то типа поиска по всем репозиториям чтоб знать какой репозиторий подключать?

И второе, как в существующем репозитории однозначно найти нужную версию пакета? Где-то `php 5.4` называется `php54`, где-то `php` просто, где-то `php54` и т.д. это не стандартизировано, синтаксис названия пакетов?

Спасибо за внимание и ответы.

Comment: Ответ вам нужен только по CentOS или любым системам с менеджером как RPM  в качестве бэкенда? Вы хотите просканировать репозитории?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Первое**

Вряд ли у вас получится искать по репозиториям если они еще не доступны в вашей системе. Отмечу, что одни из самых популярных для CentOS - это EPEL и RPM-FUSION содержат много, чего нет в стандартной поставке.

```
~# yum -y install epel-release
```

**Второе**

Смотрим какие доступны репозитории, пакеты и что можно обновить на системе:

```
~# yum repolist
~# yum list available
~# yum list updates
```

По желанию грепайте или используйте пейджеры.

Если знаете примерно как нанизывается, то ищем так:

```
~# yum search php
~# yum info *php*
```

**Ссылки**

- https://access.redhat.com/sites/default/files/attachments/rh_yum_cheatsheet_1214_jcs_print-1.pdf
- https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL
- https://rpmfusion.org/Configuration/
- https://rpmfind.net/

Comment: О, благодарю! Особенно cheatsheet как раз то что нужно! Да, EPEL думаю тоже будет достаточно.

Comment: @MihailPolitaev помогло решить проблему?